# Convert output shell to JSON

Tags: linux, shell, sh, send, except

I have 3 files that are responsible for connecting a firewall and bringing me in response CPU usage, I would like to convert output .exp to JSON, how to do that?

> monitor.exp:

```
# It has more data above, I posted only the part that matters

expect "#"
send "\ r"

expect "#"
send "show cpu usage \ r"

expect "#"
send "exit \ r"}
}
```

> monitor.conf:

```
10.0.0.0:10.0.0.1:local-dns:admin@admin#:Brazil
```

> monitor.sh:

```
for i in `cat /tmp/monitoring/monitor.conf | grep -v ^#`
do
bindip=`echo $i|cut -d: -f1`
endip=`echo $i|cut -d: -f2`
name=`echo $i|cut -d: -f3`
pass=`echo $i|cut -d: -f4`
company=`echo $i|cut -d: -f5`
/usr/bin/expect -f /tmp/monitoring/monitor.exp $bindip $endip $name $pass $company
done
```

> The output show:

```
firewall-customer/pri/act#
firewall-custome/pri/act# show cpu usage
CPU utilization for 5 seconds = 90%; 1 minute: 85%; 5 minutes: 80%
```

> Desired:

```
{'cpu usage': 'CPU utilization for 5 seconds = 90%; 1 minute: 85%; 5 minutes: 80%'}
```

Comment: You would need to specify what the JSON output should look like.  It could be as simple as `"CPU utilization for 5 seconds = 90%; 1 minute: 85%; 5 minutes: 80%"` — that's valid JSON.  I suspect you're looking for a more complex JSON structure than that, though.

Comment: ...insofar as your question is "how do I encode data retrieved with expect into JSON?", all the resources at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/JSON apply to `expect` (being itself a TCL extension). Note in particular the link therein included to `jq`, which we have many existing Q&A entries telling you how to use.

Comment: @LuisHenrique, `{'cpu usage': 'CPU utilization for 5 seconds = 90%; 1 minute: 85%; 5 minutes: 80%'}` is not valid JSON. JSON only allows double quotes, not single quotes, to have syntactic meaning. If what you really want is *Python* data (which *does* allow single quotes in that context), consider using the native-Python library `pexpect` instead of TCL-based `expect`.

Comment: BTW, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Much more efficient to get rid of all the `echo | cut` and do `while IFS=: read -r bindip endip name pass company; do [[ $bindip = #* ]] && continue;  ...; done </tmp/monitoring/monitor.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this in bash rather than in expect:

```
regex=$'CPU utilization for [^\r\n]*'
output=$(/usr/bin/expect -f monitor.exp "$bindip" "$endip" "$name" "$pass" "$company")
if [[ $output =~ $regex ]]; then
  jq -nc --arg cpu_usage "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" '{"cpu usage": $cpu_usage}'
fi
```

In bash, `[[ $var =~ $regex ]]` matches the content of `$var` against the regex in `$regex`, and then puts the results in an array called `BASH_REMATCH`.